# Android webview shouldOverrideUrlLoading method is not called

Tags: android

Android webview shouldOverrideUrlLoading method is not called onclick of a link which have pdf file

Code :

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
    if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
        return true;
    } else {
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: if url contains a simple html page, then the method will be called but if url contains the pdf file (address of pdf file), shouldOverrideUrlLoading method will be not called

Answer (score -2):

Try This

```
private class WebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // check here the url
            if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            } else {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, It will load the webpage again and again infinitely. and the actual problem remains as it is.

Comment: can you share the url which you want to load.

Comment: http://www.upsc.gov.in/  - web view loads this webpage but does not loads the internal page which contains pdf file (shouldOverrideUrlLoading method is not called onclick of a link which have pdf file)

Comment: @Juned kindly check my updated answer and it is working fine for me. Let me know the status for you.

Comment: no sir, same problem persists. it opens the normal html page but does not the pdf file. Have you tried to open the pdf file?

Comment: yes, it is working from my end. Just share your file.

Comment: Are you using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method?